# Source from vendor loaded and compiled as files from src directory

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I am trying the new Symfony4 (framework bundle) and I wanted to move some my reusable classes from src directory to vendor one (loaded via composer PSR-4).

So I created a package (new git repository), added classes there (into src directory), added PSR-4 configuration into package's composer.json like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "\\": "src/" }
}
```

and I ran `composer require <name_of_my_package>` and I dumped autoload.

All went smooth, but when I wanted to access any class from my package - for my surprise - Symfony cannot find and use any of these classes (even though they are in autoload files of composer).

I think that I need to somehow add these classes to Symfony container builder, but I am not sure how.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: add an example of how you tried to use your package

Comment: "\\" makes no sense as a psr4 namespace.  "" might work but more than likely you need something like "MyPrefix\\MyBundle\\" Look at some of the other bundles for examples.